# SP2013: "Blog Posts" web part gives error for some blogs

Tags: 2013, blog

I have 23 blog sites that I've migrated from SP2010. Content wise things appears to be OK, except that the SP2010 `Posts` web part wouldn't render. I've just finished going through all 23 blogs replacing the `Posts` web part with the SP2013 one.

In two blogs I'm having trouble changing the post layout (from the Blog Tools web part). When I do my list of posts is replaced with a repeated error message:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference
>
> TypeError: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

My steps are:

1. Remove existing web part (either SP2010 version or broken SP2013 version)
2. Add new SP2013 `Posts` web part
3. Edit the web part
4. Change the `Selected View` to be `Summary View`, click OK
5. Select "Inline" from the Blog Tools web part ***this is where it shows the error**

I've repeated the above steps successfully for 21 of the 23 blogs, but for 2 blogs the 5th step shows the error above. Before I do step 5, the posts in the blog (if there are any) are shown in List form, with the option to add more posts or change the view. I need to use the Inline layout.

Can anyone shed any light as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a while, but I figured it out. The `property 'id'` mentioned in the error was referring to the `Created By` field being blank. Initially the blog posts had come from a third party social community application, which I had exported and imported into SharePoint 2010.

While I had completed all the fields that SP2010 needed, SP2013 introduced some new requirements when rendering the web parts, which were not complete.

In the case of my two offending blogs, there were a couple of posts without the `Created By` field. Once I removed these posts the web part rendered correctly.

---

Hope this info helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This error came up when i created a blog post in SharePoint 2013 from User1 account (Full Control on site) and then open the same blog post with User2 account which had read only permissions on the site. Later on this issue happened for all of the users except the blog post author.

I installed SharePoint 2013 SP1 (15.0.4569.1000) on top of SharePoint 2013 RTM (15.0.4420.1017) which fixed the issue.

Try below link for more details.

http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/04/sharepoint-2013-blog-post-error.html